# How to search with a regular expression for strings in a range of cells in Excel?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Is there any way of using some form of regular expressions for searching a string in a range of cells in Excel using VBA?

I am searching currently for specific strings and change them using an array with the array being declared at top. To make the search better, I'm trying to figure out a way in which the needle = the array of strings I've given plus any wildcards (*) and something like if it contains at least one `a` which I think is `[a]{1}`. But I have no idea on how to write it as a regex.

As you can see bellow the regex would need to fall into the code line 
`needle = adminBad(i) & "*" & "regex"`

```
' Range of cells
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim needle As String
Set myRange = Range("R1:R100")

Dim i As Integer
Dim arrayLength As Integer

'Loop through each cell in the range for Administrator
For Each myCell In myRange
        ' set the arrayLength to equal the arrays length
        arrayLength = UBound(adminBad)
        ' Loop through the array changing i
        For i = 0 To arrayLength
        ' Set needle to be the arrays current word and a wildcard
        needle = adminBad(i) & "*"
            ' if myCell is like anything in the current array then change to the correct name
            If myCell Like needle Then

            myCell.Value = Correct(0)



            End If
        ' increment the loop so i = i + i and do the if statement again checking for a new word
        Next i
' end loop
```

Comment: Not understanding the spec for the cell. It has to contain one "a", and what?

Comment: the cells contain messed up words and im sorting through them looking for key spelling errors and i wanted to know if i can make the search include if a cell contains 0 or 1 character or even 3 of the same character such as a

Comment: @Jimjebus No need for regex if you want to test for one "a".  Just use **myCell Like "\*a\*"**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for being a pain i figured out what i wanted to do partially,

Using "[A-Z]" Regex allows me more control over what i was looking for in cells